# How do I return the first position of a value in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to create a function that will return the first position of 140 or higher in a list. My code will return every instance where 140 is present.

The list looks something like this `[[0.1,1.2,12.2,140.1,32],[0.2,2.2,222,11,32],[142,3.2,32.2,140.3,32],[0.4,4.2,42.2,140.4,192],[0.5,5.2,52.2,14.5,32]]`

This is the function:

```
def val_return(prices):
    for i in range (0, len(prices)):
        for j in range (0, len(prices[i])):
            if prices[i][j] > 140:
                return (j)
            elif prices [i][j] < 139:
                pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by returning every instance? Provide your desired output and your current output.

Comment: What output do you want?  Is it just `3`?

Comment: I want the function to return 3, 2, 0, 3.

Comment: 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4 is what the function returns I need the first number higher than 140 from each list

Comment: @callumthomas086 You are welcome. Just select that as your answer.

Comment: That answer *DOES NOT* give you "*the first number higher than 140 from each list*". If you want just the answer `3` then that that is fine but you have clearly stated other expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem is with missing `=` when you are comparing with 140. Also, the `elif` part is extra:

```
def val_return(prices):
   result = []
   for i in range (len(prices)):
      for j in range (len(prices[i])):
         if prices[i][j] >= 140:
            result.append(j)
            pass
   return result
```

The output:

```
[3, 2, 0, 3]
```

This is a more Pythonic way of doing your job:

```
def val_return(prices):
    return [next((each_element[1] for each_element in zip(each_row, range(len(each_row))) if each_element[0] >= 140), None) for each_row in prices]
```

Comment: While I agree that this is a good simplification (and slight correction) to the original code, does it not give essentially the same answer as the original `3`?

Comment: Ya, what I am saying is this is a great simplification, but if `3` is not the answer the OP wants, neither their code not this give what they want.

Comment: @JonSG The question owner hasn't provided a sample. Now that he added the sample I corrected my answer to match his need.

Comment: This answer *DOES NOT* give you "the first number higher than 140 from each list". If this actually answers your question please edit your question. This is essentially the same code as you started with. It gives you the index of the first item gte 140 period.